# $\lim_{n\to \infty} n^3(\frac{3}{4})^n$

Tags: calculus, limits

I have the sequence $a_n=(n^3)\big(\frac{3}{4}\big)^n$
and I need to find whether it converges or not and the limit.

I took the common ratio which is $\frac{3 (n+1)^3}{4 n^3}$ and since $\big|\frac{3}{4}\big|<1$ it converges.
I don't know how to find the limit from here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $\frac {a_{n+1}} {a_n} \to l$ with $|l|<1$ then $a_n \to 0$. (In fact the series $\sum a_n$ converges).

In this case $\frac {a_{n+1}} {a_n} =(1+\frac 1 n)^{3}(\frac 3 4) \to \frac 3 4$.

Comment: What is the limit tho?

Comment: @GeorgeDaravigkas Your question is already answered

Comment: Pardon me but my mind is blurry. I can see that he proves how the sequence converges but i can't understand how he finds the limit.

Comment: $a_n \to 0$ mean s that the limit of $(a_n)$ is $0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I see, i didn't know this terminology. I also want to ask how would you solve this limit if it wasn't a sequence. Can you apply this method for normal limit exercises?

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways to approach this problem.  As others have mentioned, the convergence of $\displaystyle \sum^\infty n^3(3/4)^n$ implies $n^3(3/4)^n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, and it looks like this is what you're trying to exploit.

> **Exercise**: If $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n \neq 0$, prove that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ cannot converge.

I'm a fan of logarithms myself, so here is another approach:

We have $\ln \Big( n^3(3/4)^n \Big) = 3\ln(n) + n \ln(3/4)$.  Notice that $3/4 < 1$, so its natural log will be negative; we can rearrange the expression to emphasize this:

$$3\ln(n) + n \ln(3/4) \ = \ 3 \ln(n) - n \ln(4/3)$$

At this point, we note that the linear term grows faster than the logarithmic term, so we see that $\ln(a_n) \to - \infty$, and because the natural logarithm is a continuous function, we can conclude that $a_n \to 0$.

If you feel that the "grows faster" argument is hand-wavy, you can make it rigorous by taking a derivative, wherein you'll find that it's negative for all $x$ beyond $x \approx 10.4$ and tending to $-\ln(4/3)$, implying unbounded growth toward $- \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

> I can see that he proves how the sequence converges but i can't understand how he finds the limit.

You seem to mix (the convergence of) sequence and series.

> I took the common ratio which is $\frac{3}{4}$ and since $|\frac{3}{4}|<1$ it converges.

If by *"it converges"* you mean that the series $\sum a_n$ converges, because you seem to have applied the [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test), then - a fortiori - you also have $a_n \to 0$, since:
$$\sum a_n \;\mbox{ converges } \implies a_n \to 0$$

Comment: Is there any way to solve this limit other than the ratio test?